# how to enable Hyper-V for Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm trying to windows phone app development, I'm using visual studio 2013 ultimate
edition. But I open the windows
phone emulator, windows says "Hyper-V is't on". after I turn on the hyper v in
windows feature on off but after restarting
my machine getting error windows can't enable this feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

I'm using this documentation but can't find good solution.
according to this article, Microsoft says turn off USB 3.0 in the bios and turn on hyper-v in the bios.
but my bios screen haven't this features.

my laptop brand Acer e1-572g, OS. windows 8.1 update 1
my laptop available hyper v and Hardware SLAT
(I checked the hyper-v availability and hardware slat using cpuZ tool and SLAT tool)

Comment: Are you running Windows 8.1 Pro?

Comment: Yes i using windows 8.1 pro(update 1)

Comment: I'm guessing you're not also running VM Ware?  The USB3.0 thing is a fix for certain types of Gigabyte motherboard only.  I would double check your enable/disable extended instructions sets in the BIOS. It might be cryptic option like "Enable Virtualization" or "Intel(R) Virtulazation Technology" and "Intel(R) VT-d Feature... etc etc.

Comment: thanks your reply. but my bios screen haven't advanced tab or any Virtulazation Technology on off feature or usb 3.0 feature. this is cpuz report https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Kb4ynV1EoTTUJfWU9PM09TZlk/edit?usp=sharing